# OpenCV Java bindings link error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, opencv

there's the following error when running my project with java + opencv in Eclipse (Java10, MacOS Sierra):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method) ~[opencv-342.jar:unknown]
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:26) ~[opencv-342.jar:unknown]
at org.opencv.core.MatOfByte.<init>(MatOfByte.java:12) ~[opencv-342.jar:unknown]
at de.mbs.docscanner.scan.PrepareImageService.prepare(PrepareImageService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
```

My setup:

1. Build OpenCV from Source using Homebrew to enable java bindings
2. Place resulting jar with mvn install plugin in my local maven repo
3. Setup Spring Boot project and add "my" opencv release as maven dependency
4. Import maven project in Eclipse
5. Set java.library.path to /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.2/share/OpenCV/java in Run/Debug settings

Doing a maven build on cmdline and running the project with

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.2/share/OpenCV/java -jar target/docscanner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

works fine, problem occurs only when running from Eclipse. Spring boot app start shows no problem (Tomcat based web app), error comes up when executing the code below.

Code parts:

```
@Service
public class PrepareImageService {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public ScanResult prepare(InputStream input, MediaType mediaType) throws IOException {

        ScanResult scanResult = new ScanResult();
        scanResult.setContentType(mediaType);
        scanResult.getImages().put(IMG_TYPE.ORIGINAL, StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(input));
        MatOfByte inputBuffer = new MatOfByte(scanResult.getImages().get(IMG_TYPE.ORIGINAL));
        Mat orig = Imgcodecs.imdecode(inputBuffer,    Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        // ... skipped
        return scanResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: need your code..

Comment: added code snippet

Comment: this link maybe helpful.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3315

Comment: same error with maven config fork = true

Answer (score 0):

When you are running a Native library, you need to configure where the libraries are. In this case you need the java wrapper (jar and dylib), and the opencv libraries.

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.1_2/share/java/opencv4:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.1.1_2/lib
```

Depending how opencv was installed, the path could be different. But you need both folder: java shared lib and opencv lib.